# What was the difference between "Video Low" and "Video High" on the VIC-20?

Tags: video, vic-20

I was reading about the Audio/Video port pinouts of the VIC-20 and I noticed that pin 4 is `VID L` and pin 5 is `VID H` meaning Video Low and Video High, respectively.

I'm familiar with luma, chroma, etc. but the term Video Low and Video High confuses me in the context of the VIC-20.

Can anyone shed some light on this subject?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The VLOW signal on Pin 4 of the VIC-20's monitor port has a low-pass filter applied to it, where Pin 5 (VHIGH) is not filtered. See [this post](http://sleepingelephant.com/ipw-web/bulletin/bb/viewtopic.php?t=2477&start=90), which specifically says:

> Then the signal is buffered by emitter follower Q7, with a 270 ohm load and fed to pin 5 of the video socket directly and to pin 4 via 3.9uH inductor L2 and C18 which together form a low pass filter. I need to confirm the value of C18 from a real machine, the marking is hard to make out on the scanned copy, but I would expect the cutoff frequency to be of the order of 5MHz.

Comment: Per http://www.retroisle.com/commodore/vic20/Technical/Hardware/VIC20ports.php some revisions of the machine don't include the low-pass filter and just put the same thing on both pins. The thread you link to mentions that the cost-reduced Vic-20 varied from its own schematic in combining luminance and chrominance; if the Retro Isle information is correct then I guess Commodore decided to reduce costs even further?